# What is a synthetic image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I don't understand what is a synthetic image in computer vision.
And what are the differences between optical image and synthetic image?

Here's an example of the question. It's a screen shot of a research paper:

[image: Here's an example of the question. It's a screen shot of a research paper.]

Comment: See [the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synthetic), especially 4b: “devised, arranged, or fabricated for special situations to imitate or replace usual realities”.

Comment: It depends on the context, hard to tell with only that excerpt. My guess is that they use some form of data augmentation, therefore "synthesizing" more images using the underlying dataset. An original image would therefore be an image from the original dataset, a synthetic image would be an image they generated themselfes.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "computer vision synthetic image", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 4):

A real image is obtained by an imaging device such as a camera, which converts the light from a scene to pixel values. Due to the image formation process that obeys the laws of physics, real images are rich, complex and often noisy and textured. The real world contains a lot of information.

A synthetic image is obtained "out of the blue" by pure computation, i.e. by modelling the real world and simulating the laws of optics.

Two decades ago, you could spot a synthetic image at a glance, because it was lacking realism and was obtained through too simple models (in part due to heavy computation costs). This is no more true nowadays, they tend to be indistinguishable.

Note that in scientific contexts, they can be using very simple images (say a chessboard) for experimental purposes, for instance testing an image filter.

For instance, the scene below has been synthetized by armies of researchers, with the goal of finding the most realistic lighting simulation. This room never existed.

[image]